# What is the behavior of O_APPEND with lseek: can you rewrite a file opened in O_APPEND?

Tags: files, c, io

The docs on `man lseek` say,

> If the `O_APPEND` file status flag is set on the open file description, then a `write(2)` always moves the file offset to the end of the file, regardless of the use of `lseek()`.

It doesn't say whether or not it moves the file offset to the end, before or after the `write(2)` call.

Is it possible when a file is open with `O_APPEND` to `lseek` to the top and rewrite the file?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible when a file is open with `O_APPEND` to `lseek` to the top and rewrite the file?

No.

Per the [POSIX documentation for `write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation.

You **can** use `pwrite()`, however:

> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set). The first three arguments to `pwrite()` are the same as `write()` with the addition of a fourth argument offset for the desired position inside the file. ...

You'd just have to manage the offsets yourself.

Unfortunately, [`pwrite()` is broken on Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS):

> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
> have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.
> However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
> appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
> `offset`.

So on Linux there's no way to rewrite a file opened with `O_APPEND`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't rewrite the file. The file offset is being set to the end before every `write` is executed.